# Does Xamarin support HEVC video recording on Android API24 and up?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, hevc, h.265

In Android SDK documentation, the [MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.html) enum has the value HEVC for H.265, but Xamarin's [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Media.VideoEncoder/) for the same enum does not have it. So does Xamarin support this feature?

Comment: Yes, have you looked at the actual enum when your `<TargetFramework>` is >= API 24?

Comment: As a secondary item, whenever you're in doubt of something in Android documentation, use an assembly browser to double check!

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit confused because I saw the value in the actual enum but not in the doc